# A lower bound for the fractional part involving logarithms

Tags: number-theory

My problem is the following: I would like to find a lower bound for the fractional part $\left\{\frac{\log m}{\log 2}\right\}$ where $m$ is a positive integer (not a power of $2$) in the range $3\leq m\leq 3.4\cdot 10^{42}$. Unfortunately, due to the size of the $m$ I was not able to use Mathematica software directly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The minimum non-zero fractional part probably occurs when $m=2^{141}+1$ because 141 is the integer part of the base 2 log of your maximum m

Comment: log m/log 2 can not be integer, because m is not a power of 2.

Comment: @WW1 but how to take the word "probably" off. I got your idea, but I can not see why this is the minimum.

Comment: @Jean because the derivative of log is monotonically decreasing

Comment: @WW1:  spot on.  That should be an answer.  You can get an approximate (but very close) value from the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)\approx x$ because $x$ is so small.

Comment: @Jean : In the range $3\le m\le 3.4\times 10^{42}$ there are many powers of $2.$ For those values of $m,$ the fractional part is $0. \qquad$

Comment: might be easier to bound using 

$$f(2^k+1)-f(2^k) < f'(2^k) $$
I don't want to officially post an answer because I don't really know what number theory is, I might be giving stupid advice.

Answer (score 0):

Write $m=2^k+n$ with $k$ as large as possible.  The fractional part of the expression increases as $n$ increases within a value of $k$, so the minimum will come from some $2^k+1.$  $\frac{\log m}{\log 2}=\frac{\log (2^k+1)}{\log 2}=k+\frac{\log (1+2^{-k})}{\log 2}$, so the fractional part is $\frac{\log (1+2^{-k})}{\log 2}$.  This is minimized when $k$ is as large as possible.  In your range the largest $k$ is $141$ so the minimum fractional value is $\frac{\log (1+2^{-141})}{\log 2}.$  Using the fact that $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for $x \ll 1$ this is about $\frac {2^{-141}}{\log 2} \approx 5.175 \cdot 10^{-43}$